# Login with a Facebook Android SDK application crashes

Tags: android, facebook

I am getting this error when I develop the app on Android 1.5 or later:

```
10-05 15:20:14.586: INFO/WindowManager(169): Read next event 0
10-05 15:20:14.586: ERROR/WORD------------------(4291): JACK BLACK
10-05 15:20:14.586: ERROR/HINT---------------------(4291): Starred in "High Fidelity".
10-05 15:20:14.586: WARN/WindowManager(169): No window to dispatch pointer action 0
10-05 15:20:14.656: INFO/KeyInputQueue(169): Enqueueing touch event1
10-05 15:20:14.656: INFO/WindowManager(169): Read next event 1
10-05 15:20:14.656: WARN/WindowManager(169): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
10-05 15:20:14.806: INFO/KeyInputQueue(169): Enqueueing touch event0
10-05 15:20:14.806: INFO/WindowManager(169): Read next event 0
10-05 15:20:14.806: INFO/WindowManager(169): Delivering pointer 0 > Window{4a74bf68 com.spice.hangman/com.spice.hangman.GameScreenClassic paused=false}
10-05 15:20:14.836: INFO/KeyInputQueue(169): Enqueueing touch event1
10-05 15:20:14.836: INFO/WindowManager(169): Read next event 1
10-05 15:20:14.936: INFO/DEBUG(3186):
10-05 15:20:14.936: INFO/DEBUG(3186): Build fingerprint: 'Samsung/GT-S5830/GT-S5830/GT-S5830:2.2.1/FROYO/DDKA7:user/release-keys'
10-05 15:20:14.936: INFO/DEBUG(3186): pid: 4291, tid: 4291  >>> com.spice.hangman <<<
10-05 15:20:14.936: INFO/DEBUG(3186): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadbaad
10-05 15:20:14.936: INFO/DEBUG(3186):  r0 00000000  r1 80000000  r2 00000027  r3 00000000
10-05 15:20:14.946: INFO/DEBUG(3186):  r4 00000000  r5 deadbaad  r6 00001730  r7 00000000
10-05 15:20:14.946: INFO/DEBUG(3186):  r8 ab215344  r9 00000000  10 00b899b8  fp 0002f3d2
10-05 15:20:14.946: INFO/DEBUG(3186):  ip ffffffff  sp bef06108  lr afd154d5  pc afd11dd4  cpsr 40000030
10-05 15:20:14.946: INFO/DEBUG(3186):  d0  4342000043bb0000  d1  4130000043370000
10-05 15:20:14.946: INFO/DEBUG(3186):  d2  43ba80003f800000  d3  3ff0000000000000
10-05 15:20:14.946: INFO/DEBUG(3186):  d4  4960000000000000  d5  4066e00000000000
10-05 15:20:14.956: INFO/DEBUG(3186):  d6  41d000003f800000  d7  0000000041c80000
10-05 15:20:14.956: INFO/DEBUG(3186):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
10-05 15:20:14.956: INFO/DEBUG(3186):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
10-05 15:20:14.956: INFO/DEBUG(3186):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
10-05 15:20:14.956: INFO/DEBUG(3186):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
10-05 15:20:14.956: INFO/DEBUG(3186):  scr 60000012
10-05 15:20:14.996: INFO/KeyInputQueue(169): Enqueueing touch event0
10-05 15:20:15.026: INFO/DEBUG(3186):          #00  pc 00011dd4  /system/lib/libc.so
10-05 15:20:15.026: INFO/DEBUG(3186):          #01  pc 0000be2c  /system/lib/libc.so
10-05 15:20:15.026: INFO/DEBUG(3186): code around pc:
10-05 15:20:15.026: INFO/DEBUG(3186): afd11db4 1c2bd00b 2d00682d e026d1fb 2b0068db
10-05 15:20:15.026: INFO/DEBUG(3186): afd11dc4 4e17d003 51a02001 4d164798 24002227
10-05 15:20:15.026: INFO/DEBUG(3186): afd11dd4 f7fb702a 2106ee14 ef10f7fc 05592380
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186): afd11de4 6091aa01 1c116054 94012006 eab6f7fc
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186): afd11df4 2200a905 f7fc2002 f7fbeac2 2106ee00
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186): code around lr:
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186): afd154b4 b0834a0d 589c447b 26009001 686768a5
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186): afd154c4 220ce008 2b005eab 1c28d003 47889901
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186): afd154d4 35544306 d5f43f01 2c006824 b003d1ee
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186): afd154e4 bdf01c30 0002ae6c 000000d4 1c0fb5f0
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186): afd154f4 43551c3d a904b087 1c16ac01 604d9004
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186): stack:
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef060c8  00000015
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef060cc  afd1454b  /system/lib/libc.so
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef060d0  afd405a0  /system/lib/libc.so
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef060d4  afd4054c  /system/lib/libc.so
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef060d8  00000000
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef060dc  afd154d5  /system/lib/libc.so
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef060e0  00000008
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef060e4  afd1451d  /system/lib/libc.so
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef060e8  00000000
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef060ec  afd40328  /system/lib/libc.so
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef060f0  00000000
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef060f4  00001730
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef060f8  00000000
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef060fc  afd147bb  /system/lib/libc.so
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef06100  df002777
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef06104  e3a070ad
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186): #00 bef06108  000c57e0  [heap]
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef0610c  00000000
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef06110  afd418e4  /system/lib/libc.so
10-05 15:20:15.036: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef06114  afd10520  /system/lib/libc.so
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef06118  afd40328  /system/lib/libc.so
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef0611c  fffffbdf
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef06120  afd40328  /system/lib/libc.so
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef06124  afd4172c  /system/lib/libc.so
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef06128  0000a000  [heap]
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef0612c  afd0be31  /system/lib/libc.so
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186): #01 bef06130  afd40328  /system/lib/libc.so
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef06134  afd0be31  /system/lib/libc.so
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef06138  00000000
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef0613c  00084cb8  [heap]
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef06140  000c3ff0  [heap]
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef06144  00084cd0  [heap]
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef06148  00084aa0  [heap]
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef0614c  afd0cd91  /system/lib/libc.so
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef06150  00001404
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef06154  ab1a3944  /system/lib/libskia.so
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef06158  00084cb8  [heap]
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef0615c  000c3f78  [heap]
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef06160  ab214470  /system/lib/libskia.so
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef06164  00597698  [heap]
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef06168  00000cb0
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef0616c  afd0cd91  /system/lib/libc.so
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef06170  000c3f78  [heap]
10-05 15:20:15.046: INFO/DEBUG(3186):     bef06174  ab14c5a4  /system/lib/libskia.so
10-05 15:20:15.076: INFO/KeyInputQueue(169): Enqueueing touch event1
10-05 15:20:15.206: INFO/KeyInputQueue(169): Enqueueing touch event0
10-05 15:20:15.266: INFO/KeyInputQueue(169): Enqueueing touch event1
10-05 15:20:16.776: INFO/DEBUG(3186): dumpmesg > /data/log/dumpstate_app_native.log
10-05 15:20:16.786: INFO/BootReceiver(169): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_02 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
10-05 15:20:16.886: VERBOSE/AudioFlinger(94): Audio hardware entering standby, mixer 0xbb50, mSuspended 0
10-05 15:20:16.906: VERBOSE/AudioFlinger(94): MixerThread 0xbb50 TID 148 going to sleep
10-05 15:20:19.836: WARN/WindowManager(169): Key dispatching timed out sending to com.spice.hangman/com.spice.hangman.GameScreenClassic
10-05 15:20:19.836: WARN/WindowManager(169): Previous dispatch state: {{KeyEvent{action=1 code=4 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=158 mFlags=8} to Window{4a5fd138 com.spice.hangman/com.spice.hangman.Stats_AchievementsScreen paused=false} @ 1317808203683 lw=Window{4a5fd138 com.spice.hangman/com.spice.hangman.Stats_AchievementsScreen paused=false} lb=android.os.BinderProxy@4a6711f8 fin=false gfw=true ed=true tts=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=Window{4a5fd138 com.spice.hangman/com.spice.hangman.Stats_AchievementsScreen paused=false}}}
10-05 15:20:19.836: WARN/WindowManager(169): Current dispatch state: {{null to Window{4a74bf68 com.spice.hangman/com.spice.hangman.GameScreenClassic paused=false} @ 1317808219838 lw=Window{4a74bf68 com.spice.hangman/com.spice.hangman.GameScreenClassic paused=false} lb=android.os.BinderProxy@4a7e08a8 fin=false gfw=true ed=true tts=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=Window{4a74bf68 com.spice.hangman/com.spice.hangman.GameScreenClassic paused=false}}}
10-05 15:20:20.836: WARN/PowerManagerService(169): Timer 0x7->0x3|0x0
10-05 15:20:20.836: INFO/PowerManagerService(169): Ulight 7->3|0
```

The application also uses the Facebook Android SDK. When I login with Facebook and come back to any screen after a while, this message will come when I switch from one activity to another.

- Phone: Samsung Ace i5830
- 0S: 2.2.1

Comment: Have you tried executing it in 1.6? Because most of the api's for 1.5 are deprecated.

Comment: Yes @Rashmi.B is right according to [this](http://ericosgood.com/prog/facebook-android-sdk-tutorial/) tutorial

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned earlier, 1.5 APIs are deprecated. Try developing using 1.6 SDK.

Comment: I am using the latest sdk ......>android 1.5 means my application support all the phones from 1.5 to latest os.

Comment: I understand Chandrakant, but since most of the phones these days have 2.1+ OS, Facebook API supports 1.6 onwards, which is why you cannot develop for 1.5

Comment: This exception is coming on Samsung ace  which is having 2.1 os..............but i am not sure can this exception will come due to memory.........

Comment: I am not asking about the SDK you are testing the app on, the SDK version on which you are building the app. In your manifest file, the app's minSDK must be 1.6.