# Login with facebook android sdk app crash API 4

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, crash, segmentation-fault

Login with `Facebook Android SDK` **crash** in a second after "publish to wall" dialog appeared. I found descriptions of probably the some issue here:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/79

and here,

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/86,

but there is no any answer.

The `SDK` worked fine until some moment. After that something happened. Probably, Facebook changed something. Anyway it does not work now.

There is no exception information, program *terminated by signal 11* (SIGSEGV). I have no idea, how to work around it.

Also, the some issue in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777244/facebook-example-not-working. Again, no workaround, no solution.

It happen on API 4 (Android 1.6). On Android 2.2 everything works fine. But I need my app works without crashes on API 4!!!

Probably in here: [Login with a Facebook Android SDK application crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710944/login-with-facebook-android-sdk-app-crash) the some issue, but in my case it happen not only on API 3, but API 4 also.

```
10-21 16:28:41.337: D/Facebook-WebView(583): Webview loading URL: https://www.facebook.com/login.php?m=m&next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Ffeed%3F_path%3Dfeed%26app_id%3D209093762443963%26redirect_uri%3Dfbconnect%253A%252F%252Fsuccess%26display%3Dtouch%26link%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fmarket.android.com%252Fdetails%253Fid%253Dcom.tfd.mobile.TfdSearch%26name%3DThe%2BFree%2BDictionary%2Bfor%2BAndroid%26from_login%3D1&refsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Flogin.php&refid=9
10-21 16:28:42.577: D/dalvikvm(583): GC freed 7108 objects / 1161896 bytes in 76ms
10-21 16:28:43.608: D/Facebook-WebView(583): Webview loading URL: https://m.facebook.com/dialog/feed?_path=feed&app_id=209093762443963&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&display=touch&link=https%3A%2F%2Fmarket.android.com%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.tfd.mobile.TfdSearch&name=The+Free+Dictionary+for+Android&from_login=1&refsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Flogin.php&refid=9&_rdr
10-21 16:28:46.137: D/dalvikvm(583): GC freed 9201 objects / 688976 bytes in 150ms
10-21 16:28:48.498: W/InputManagerService(51): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@43935f68
10-21 16:28:48.657: I/DEBUG(27): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-21 16:28:48.657: I/DEBUG(27): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic/:1.6/Donut/20842:eng/test-keys'
10-21 16:28:48.667: I/DEBUG(27): pid: 583, tid: 591  >>> com.tfd.mobile.TfdSearch <<<
10-21 16:28:48.667: I/DEBUG(27): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000000
10-21 16:28:48.667: I/DEBUG(27):  r0 00000001  r1 00000000  r2 00000001  r3 00000000
10-21 16:28:48.667: I/DEBUG(27):  r4 00659380  r5 00000001  r6 ac128344  r7 00000001
10-21 16:28:48.667: I/DEBUG(27):  r8 44d9e234  r9 006420b0  10 44d9e1cc  fp 00000000
10-21 16:28:48.667: I/DEBUG(27):  ip 00000001  sp 44d9e190  lr 00000001  pc ac031a18  cpsr 60000010
10-21 16:28:48.727: I/DEBUG(27):          #00  pc 00031a18  /system/lib/libsgl.so
10-21 16:28:48.737: I/DEBUG(27):          #01  pc 00030c84  /system/lib/libsgl.so
10-21 16:28:48.737: I/DEBUG(27):          #02  pc 000357a4  /system/lib/libsgl.so
10-21 16:28:48.737: I/DEBUG(27):          #03  pc 00035ed4  /system/lib/libsgl.so
10-21 16:28:48.737: I/DEBUG(27):          #04  pc 00035a8c  /system/lib/libsgl.so
10-21 16:28:48.737: I/DEBUG(27):          #05  pc 00035b28  /system/lib/libsgl.so
10-21 16:28:48.737: I/DEBUG(27):          #06  pc 00071f50  /system/lib/libsgl.so
10-21 16:28:48.737: I/DEBUG(27):          #07  pc 0003cfbc  /system/lib/libsgl.so
10-21 16:28:48.737: I/DEBUG(27):          #08  pc 001d780e  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.737: I/DEBUG(27):          #09  pc 001c97fc  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.747: I/DEBUG(27):          #10  pc 001c98ec  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.747: I/DEBUG(27):          #11  pc 001c9902  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.747: I/DEBUG(27):          #12  pc 001d7906  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.747: I/DEBUG(27):          #13  pc 001d2b6e  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.747: I/DEBUG(27):          #14  pc 001d2bd8  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.747: I/DEBUG(27):          #15  pc 001d2c94  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.747: I/DEBUG(27):          #16  pc 0021b9c0  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.747: I/DEBUG(27):          #17  pc 0022fd78  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.757: I/DEBUG(27):          #18  pc 001f89c2  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.757: I/DEBUG(27):          #19  pc 001fa58c  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.757: I/DEBUG(27):          #20  pc 00245510  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.757: I/DEBUG(27):          #21  pc 0021848e  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.757: I/DEBUG(27):          #22  pc 00205afe  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.757: I/DEBUG(27):          #23  pc 00208aca  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.757: I/DEBUG(27):          #24  pc 00205706  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.757: I/DEBUG(27):          #25  pc 001ffb90  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.767: I/DEBUG(27):          #26  pc 00208b40  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.767: I/DEBUG(27):          #27  pc 00236e28  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.767: I/DEBUG(27):          #28  pc 00238068  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.767: I/DEBUG(27):          #29  pc 00233374  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.767: I/DEBUG(27):          #30  pc 00205a28  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.767: I/DEBUG(27):          #31  pc 00205b0c  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.777: I/DEBUG(27): stack:
10-21 16:28:48.777: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e150  00659380  [heap]
10-21 16:28:48.777: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e154  ac0d1859  /system/lib/libsgl.so
10-21 16:28:48.777: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e158  00659380  [heap]
10-21 16:28:48.777: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e15c  44d9e234  
10-21 16:28:48.777: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e160  44d9e234  
10-21 16:28:48.777: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e164  ac03caac  /system/lib/libsgl.so
10-21 16:28:48.777: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e168  44d9e234  
10-21 16:28:48.777: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e16c  00000000  
10-21 16:28:48.777: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e170  00000003  
10-21 16:28:48.777: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e174  ac03cbd0  /system/lib/libsgl.so
10-21 16:28:48.777: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e178  00659380  [heap]
10-21 16:28:48.777: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e17c  00000001  
10-21 16:28:48.777: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e180  ac128344  /system/lib/libsgl.so
10-21 16:28:48.777: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e184  00000001  
10-21 16:28:48.777: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e188  df002777  
10-21 16:28:48.777: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e18c  e3a070ad  
10-21 16:28:48.777: I/DEBUG(27): #00 44d9e190  00000000  
10-21 16:28:48.777: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e194  00000000  
10-21 16:28:48.777: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e198  aa3dc5d0  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.777: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e19c  44d9e768  
10-21 16:28:48.787: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1a0  005b14d8  [heap]
10-21 16:28:48.787: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1a4  44d9fda0  
10-21 16:28:48.787: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1a8  4252dee4  
10-21 16:28:48.787: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1ac  aa24257d  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.787: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1b0  00548278  [heap]
10-21 16:28:48.787: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1b4  aa20b0fd  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.787: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1b8  44d9e5b8  
10-21 16:28:48.787: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1bc  aa20b203  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.787: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1c0  00000000  
10-21 16:28:48.787: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1c4  00000000  
10-21 16:28:48.787: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1c8  00547df8  [heap]
10-21 16:28:48.787: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1cc  aa242565  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.787: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1d0  44d9e768  
10-21 16:28:48.787: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1d4  aa20b203  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
10-21 16:28:48.787: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1d8  00000000  
10-21 16:28:48.787: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1dc  00548278  [heap]
10-21 16:28:48.797: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1e0  44d9e210  
10-21 16:28:48.797: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1e4  44d9e2a0  
10-21 16:28:48.797: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1e8  00000000  
10-21 16:28:48.797: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1ec  00000000  
10-21 16:28:48.797: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1f0  00000000  
10-21 16:28:48.797: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1f4  00547df8  [heap]
10-21 16:28:48.797: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1f8  43920000  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap-bitmap/mark/0 (deleted)
10-21 16:28:48.797: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e1fc  00000002  
10-21 16:28:48.797: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e200  00000000  
10-21 16:28:48.797: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e204  006420b0  [heap]
10-21 16:28:48.797: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e208  00000003  
10-21 16:28:48.797: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e20c  0065c5a0  [heap]
10-21 16:28:48.797: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e210  44d9e234  
10-21 16:28:48.807: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e214  0065c5e4  [heap]
10-21 16:28:48.807: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e218  4252def8  
10-21 16:28:48.807: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e21c  4252dee4  
10-21 16:28:48.807: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e220  00000001  
10-21 16:28:48.807: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e224  ac030c88  /system/lib/libsgl.so
10-21 16:28:48.807: I/DEBUG(27): #01 44d9e228  00000001  
10-21 16:28:48.807: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e22c  afe0ed94  /system/lib/libc.so
10-21 16:28:48.807: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e230  006420b0  [heap]
10-21 16:28:48.807: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e234  00000000  
10-21 16:28:48.807: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e238  00000000  
10-21 16:28:48.807: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e23c  00000000  
10-21 16:28:48.807: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e240  00000000  
10-21 16:28:48.807: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e244  00000000  
10-21 16:28:48.817: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e248  00000000  
10-21 16:28:48.817: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e24c  00000001  
10-21 16:28:48.817: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e250  00010001  [heap]
10-21 16:28:48.817: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e254  00010003  [heap]
10-21 16:28:48.817: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e258  00000001  
10-21 16:28:48.817: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e25c  0065c5c0  [heap]
10-21 16:28:48.817: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e260  0065c5e4  [heap]
10-21 16:28:48.817: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e264  00000001  
10-21 16:28:48.817: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e268  44d9fda0  
10-21 16:28:48.817: I/DEBUG(27):     44d9e26c  ac0357a8  /system/lib/libsgl.so
10-21 16:28:49.977: D/Zygote(29): Process 583 terminated by signal (11)
10-21 16:28:49.988: I/ActivityManager(51): Process com.tfd.mobile.TfdSearch (pid 583) has died.
10-21 16:28:49.988: I/WindowManager(51): WIN DEATH: Window{438acb58 com.tfd.mobile.TfdSearch/com.tfd.mobile.TfdSearch.TfdSearch paused=false}
10-21 16:28:49.988: I/WindowManager(51): WIN DEATH: Window{438ba750 com.tfd.mobile.TfdSearch/com.tfd.mobile.TfdSearch.TfdSearch paused=false}
10-21 16:28:50.037: W/UsageStats(51): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.tfd.mobile.TfdSearch
10-21 16:28:50.077: W/InputManagerService(51): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 583 uid 10024
```

Comment: Filed bug: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/292642314093388

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official answer from Facebook (http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/282710765082535):

> Mikhail,
>
> The facebook android sdk no longer supports android 1.5 and 1.6.
>   Please upgrade to the next api version.
>
> Good luck with your implementation.